# iText pdf will not open in browser

Tags: .net, pdf, itext

Pdf created with iText will not open in IE with machine that has Adobe Pro installed. Works great in otherwise. Browser setting? Thanks in advance.

related code: Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";

Comment: Have you tried opening a PDF online (not yours)?  Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

Jon's question hints at this, but let me spell it out.

I see a similar problem in that I cannot open *any* PDF in IE directly.  And here's why:

- I have Acrobat Pro (9.4 at the moment) installed, and Adobe only offers it as a 32-bit build.
- I have Windows 7 64-bit, which will only allow me to have IE 64-bit installed.
- Apps/DLLs with different bit-widths may not share a process.

  - So IE 64-bit can't talk to Acrobat 32-bit.
  - So no PDF in a browser in IE 64-bits.

I'm not sure if I should be annoyed with MS or Adobe for this one, so I'll use my wife's favorite shopping strategy (ouch) and go with "Both!"

---

There's nothing special about any given PDF that would prevent it from being opened in a browser.  If one PDF opens, *all **valid** pdfs* should open.  They might not be "optimized for web view" (AKA "linearized", set up for a progressive download), but they should still open.

It occurs to me that if your PDF is particularly large (or your connection particularly slow), you might expect the first page to pop up right away as you would get in a linearized PDF, and decide that its not working because you have to wait for the entire file to download before you can view any of it.

iText does not support linearization, at least not as of 5.0.5.  If we ever add support for it, it'll likely start life as an extra pass you have to make on an existing PDF, and eventually migrate into a more efficient implementation if people complain enough.

- PS: Linearizing large forms doesn't work all that well, because the entire form portion of the file (and any doc-level script) must be downloaded before the first page can be displayed.
- PPS: I'm pretty sure there's no point in linearizing a 1-page PDF.  The whole goal of linearization is to sort the PDF so that everything that's needed by the first page is in the front of the file, so you download that part first.  When you only have the one page to display, I believe it's all just extra overhead.